# Will setting a multicast destination address to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF make it a broadcast?

Tags: sockets, networking, multicast, broadcast

I'm working with a device that sends out UDP packets on a multicast address, however I see some packets addressed to the multicast group IP with a MAC address of FFFF.FFFF.FFFF.  From what I've read my best guess is that this is an attempt to do a network wide broadcast from the multicast group.

Here's what I know:

Multicast sends packets only to devices that are "subscribed" to the multicast group.
Each multicast group normally has its own MAC address based on the IP address of the multicast group.  A multicast packet can therefore be determined by looking at the multicast address.

A broadcast goes out to every device on the network.  To send a broadcast the destination MAC address should be set to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF.  I've also heard that broadcasts can be thought of as a special case of multicast.  My question therefore is, does setting the destination MAC to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF the only change that is needed to change a multicast frame to a broadcast frame?  If not, what else must be changed?

Answer (score 2):

> Multicast sends packets only to devices that are "subscribed" to the multicast group.

Not really. It sends to *subnets* that *contain* members of the group.

> Each multicast group normally has its own MAC address based on the IP address of the multicast group.

No.

> A multicast packet can therefore be determined by looking at the multicast address.

I suspect you meant to say 'MAC address' here, and in your title too, which is wrong, but what you actually said is more or less correct. You can determine a multicast packet by looking at the destination IP address to see whether it's a multicast address.

> A broadcast goes out to every device on the network.

Correct.

> To send a broadcast the destination MAC address should be set to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF.

The destination IP address should be set to the subnet broadcast address.

> I've also heard that broadcasts can be thought of as a special case of multicast.

No. The mechanisms are completely different.

> My question therefore is, does setting the destination MAC to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF the only change that is needed to change a multicast frame to a broadcast frame?

No, see above.

Comment: Hi EJP thanks for the response.  A couple of questions...
If mulicast groups don't have their MAC address based on their IP address then what determines their unique MAC?  My understanding was that it was linked to the Multicast group IP, but it sounds like this isn't the case.

I'm working with a device which the documentation says uses UDP multicast packets sent to a multicast IP.  What I see with wireshark is a UDP packet sent to a multicast IP address, however the destination MAC is set to FFFF.FFFF.FFFF.  I'm therefore trying to determine if this is actually a broadcast or multicast?

Comment: They don't have a unique MAC at all, as your example shows. And it's irrelevant. A datagram is a multicast if it's sent to a multicast address.